# Variable does not live long enough error in Rust

Tags: rust

Rust beginner here and just doing some learning projects, I encountered the `path does not live long enough` Error. I tried to find answers, but none of them helped me understand my core problem. I tried multiple ways to fix but nothing helped.
Line of code `match Path::new(&path).extension().and_then(OsStr::to_str){`  throws the mentioned error . And the error specifically goes away when i remove this `langs.insert(ext, 1);` line of code. I cant understand why that line causes all the problem??
**main.rs** ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=022deef72872af4256a0c6db5d37cc7a))

```
fn iterate_files(path: String, langs: &mut HashMap<&str, u16>){
    let files = fs::read_dir(&path);
    match &files{
        Ok(_) => {
            for file in files.unwrap(){
                let path: PathBuf = file.unwrap().path();
                let string_path: String = path.display().to_string();
                let temp = Path::new(&string_path).file_name().unwrap();
                if is_safe_to_iterate(temp){
                    continue;
                }
                
                match Path::new(&path).extension().and_then(OsStr::to_str){
                    None => {
                        iterate_files(string_path, langs);
                        continue;
                    },
                    Some(text) => {
                        let ext: &str = text;
                        if langs.contains_key(ext){
                            langs.insert(ext, 1);
                        }
                    }
                }

                println!("{}", path.display());
            }
        },
        Err(_) => {
            println!("Illegal File Encountered booom!! {}", path);
        },
    }
}
```

Full error message:

```
error[E0597]: `path` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:24:33
   |
12 | fn iterate_files(path: String, langs: &mut HashMap<&str, u16>) {
   |                                                    - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
24 |                 match Path::new(&path).extension().and_then(OsStr::to_str) {
   |                                 ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
32 |                             langs.insert(ext, 1);
   |                             -------------------- argument requires that `path` is borrowed for `'1`
...
38 |             }
   |             - `path` dropped here while still borrowed

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Comment: The type of `langs` is `HashMap<&str, u16>`, which means it doesn't own its keys but rather borrows them.  The problem is that the key you're attempting to insert, `ext`, only lives as long as `path` (from which it borrows).  So it cannot be inserted into a `HashMap` that outlives `path`'s scope (the end of the `for` loop) let alone the function.  You probably want `langs` to own its keys instead, i.e. have type `HashMap<String, u16>` and adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: Armed with that knowledge take another look at the *full compiler error message*, which spells it out quite clearly.  In future, have a good look at the error message first and if you still can't understand it please include it (in full) in your question.

Comment: Thank you. This solved the issue. Now I understand what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

The error with your code can be resolved by doing 2 things:

**1.** Import the relevant dependencies. The following dependencies would resolve the match issue among others

```
use hashbrown::HashMap;
use std::path::Path;
use std::fs;
use std::ffi::OsStr;
```

2. You called a function to check the temp declaration but did not define the function. **is_safe_to_iterate** should be defined before being used in the main function:

   if is_safe_to_iterate(temp){
   continue;
   }

Once you add the dependencies from 1 and define what *is_safe_to_iterate(temp)* should do your code runs fine.